# ChartJS not displaying time data using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to map out a series of data points on a given day by the hour.
Not every hour is included in the data set, however I still want to show the time from 0:00 - 23:00 and plot the data points that is available.

My error is

> This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an
>   incomplete integration was provided.

However, Looking at the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) and this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-chartjs-scales--cms-28477), I still get the error.

In my `hourlyData` set, x is the hour and y is the amount.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart_hourlycalls').getContext('2d');
  var hourlyData = [{
    "x": "1",
    "y": "1"
  }, {
    "x": "3",
    "y": "2"
  }, {
    "x": "5",
    "y": "1"
  }, {
    "x": "6",
    "y": "13"
  }, {
    "x": "7",
    "y": "13"
  }, {
    "x": "8",
    "y": "5"
  }, {
    "x": "9",
    "y": "9"
  }, {
    "x": "10",
    "y": "14"
  }, {
    "x": "11",
    "y": "24"
  }, {
    "x": "12",
    "y": "5"
  }];

  var labels = hourlyData.map(e => moment(e.x, 'HH'));
  var data = hourlyData.map(e => e.y);

  var options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Calls'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'HH a'
          }
        },
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Hour'
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
  };

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      data: data
    },
    options: options
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart_hourlycalls"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
```

as pointed out by the [doc](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Moment.js *before* Chart.js.

The Chart.js documentation could do a better job of highlighting this, but it is explained on the [installation page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html?h=moment#selecting-the-correct-build):

> The stand-alone build includes Chart.js as well as the color parsing library. If this version is used, you are ***required to include Moment.js before Chart.js*** for the functionality of the time axis.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to put the moment.js script above the chart.js. However here is an example of using moment.js that may help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58555196/12176979